# Regularity of core for the Dirichlet Laplacian

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, spectral-theory, laplacian

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^d$, $d\ge 2$, be a bounded Lipschitz domain, and consider the $L^2$-Dirichlet Laplacian $(\Delta_{2}^D,\mathscr{D}(\Delta_2^D))$ on $L^2(\Omega)$.
Say that $\mathcal C\subset \mathscr{D}(\Delta_2^D))$ is a *core* for $(\Delta_{2}^D,\mathscr{D}(\Delta_2^D))$ if $(\Delta_{2}^D,\mathscr{D}(\Delta_2^D))$ is the unique $L^2$-self-adjoint extenion of $(\Delta_{2}^D,\mathcal C)$.

> **Question:** What is the best regularity we can expect for functions in $\mathcal C$ ?

Precisely, can we expect that there exists a core $\mathcal C\subset \mathcal C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega)$ for either

0. $k=2$ and $\alpha=0$, having defined $\mathcal C^{k,0}(\Omega):= \mathcal C^k(\overline\Omega)$?
1. $k=2$ and some $\alpha>0$?
2. $k=2$ and $\alpha=1$?
3. $k\geq 3$?

> **More difficult question**: What is the maximal boundary regularity we can expect from eigenfunctions of $(\Delta_{2}^D,\mathscr{D}(\Delta_2^D))$?

The second question is intimately related to the first, since, if all eigenfunctions have regularity $\mathcal C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega)$, then their linear span is a core of regularity $\mathcal C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega)$.

*Note*: of course on somewhat nice domains we can expect $\mathcal C^\infty(\overline\Omega)\cap \mathscr{D}(\Delta_2^D)$ to be a core. This is the case on smooth domains, or domains with nice spectral properties, e.g. rectangles, on which one can prove that eigenfunctions are smooth up to the boundary.